# Packing circles in circle vs semicircle vs quarter of circle

Tags: geometry, limits, circles, packing-problem

Consider $N$ disjoint circles with radius $1$ packed into a larger 
circle $C$. Let $R$ be the smallest possible radius of $C$, allowing 
the best packing density.

Now take the $N$ unitary circles and try to pack them in two other ways, 
again searching the maximal packing density. First, let us pack them 
into two disjoint and equal semicircles; then, let us pack them into 
four disjoint and equal quarters of circle. Let $R_S$ be the smallest 
possible radius of the semicircles, and let $R_Q$ be the smallest 
possible radius of the quarters of circle, in both cases allowing the 
maximal packing density. 
Because halving a packed circle or semicircle alters the best packing disposition (hexagonal) along the division lines, we have $R_Q>R_S>R$.

I calculated the differences $(R_S-R)$ and $(R_Q-R_S)$ using the best 
packing values available to date for $N\leq400$. The result is shown in 
the following figure:

[image]

Prove or disprove that these differences converge to definite positive 
values when $N$ tends to $\infty$.

Edit: the plot might suggest some convergence towards positive values. I tried to calculate these values by determining the effect of division lines on packing, and then by focusing on the region of the semicircles nearest to the diameter, and on the regions of the quarter of circles nearest to the radia. Then, I calculated the difference between the uncovered areas over these regions, considering the unitary circles first in the best packing hexagonal arrangement, and then in the "squared" arrangement (that could probably be expected at the level of diameter and radii). However, I obtained inconsistent results.

Comment: What do you think? And what have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I edited my question with some details about what I have tried.

Comment: Maybe it would be more natural to fix $R$ and measure the  density (percent of area covered) of the various packings. For then it is clear that the packing in semicircles or in quarter circles results in lower density as $R \to 0$ (and so $N \to \infty$).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: I disagree: for $N\to\infty$, the overall density will be dominated by the interior of the circle, which will be mostly hexagonal. Effects along the border will become increasingly irrelevant for that density. The difference the question asks about is however purely due to border effects. Which is indicated by the fact that the assumed limit values would be on the same scale as the radii.

Comment: @MvG: I take your point. What I was attempting to emphasize is that in a neighborhood of the semicircle diameter, the packing will be inefficient in comparison to a packing that can fill in the gaps. But I did not capture this correctly; you are right.